# How can I make a webpage that displays a certain message based on the date?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make a webpage that based on the date, redirects to a certain webpage? Ex. it's march 22, redirects to example.com/march22

Comment: Your question is far too broad. What are you stuck on? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you looked into javascript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.